# Long table doesn't fit on page width - big left margin

Tags: spacing, longtable, booktabs

I would like to gain more space for my table by removing the white space on the left but I'm not able to find a good solution. Anyone can help? If possible I would keep the cell and font size.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,onecolumn]{extbook}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{unitsdef}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{SEQUENZE}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \caption{abc}
    \begin{longtable}{>{\centering\footnotesize\bfseries}m{3cm}>{\centering\footnotesize}m{2cm}>{\centering\footnotesize}m{2cm}>{\centering\footnotesize}m{2cm}>{\centering\footnotesize}m{2cm}>{\centering\footnotesize}m{2cm}>{\centering\footnotesize}m{2cm}>{\centering\footnotesize}m{2cm}>{\centering\footnotesize}m{2cm}>{\centering\footnotesize\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}
        \toprule
        TIPOLOGIA & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        PESATURA & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        PIANO & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        \# STRATI & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        SPESSORI (mm) & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        GAP (mm) & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        RIEMPIMENTO & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        COD AX & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        COD SAG & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        COD COR & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        FOV (mm) & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        RFOV (\%) & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        \# ECHI & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        GAP ECHI (ms) & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        NSA & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        TE (ms) & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        TI (ms) & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        MATRICE & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        AA & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        DE & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        REPHASE & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \midrule
        ECHO SHIFT & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880 & 880x880\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: this what i have achived so far]

Comment: What is your problem with the table?  With what you've given, my response would be to remove the table and say "all results are 880x880", but I'm guessing you have different data than that.

Comment: there is no point in using longtable inside table. there can be no page break in a table

Answer (score 1):

If the table doesn't fit on your page, your table is likely wrong and you shouldn't change the page but the table. My first suggestion would be to switch to landscape format or use rotate box to rotate only the content.

Nevertheless, here is an ugly solution I do definitely not recommend:

```
.... 
\begin{longtable}{>{\hspace*{-150pt}\centering\footnotesize\bfseries}m{0.01cm}>{\centering\footnotesize}m{2cm}>{\centering\footnotesize}m{2cm}>{\centering\footnotesize}m{2cm}>{\centering
.....
```

You should be able to adjust the hlines in a similar manner with the hspace*.

Answer (score 0):

- your table is to wide that can fit in portrait  oriented page.
- to have `\subsubsection` and table on the same page, only table should be rotated for 90 degrees by use of `sideways` environment defined in the `rotating` package
- for table I would use ``tabularray`package with`booktabs`library (which load`booktabs` package):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{extbook}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}                % <--- new
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {4}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{rotating}                  % <--- new
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.05}      % <--- new
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.95} % <--- new
 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{SEQUENZE}

    \begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    
    \begin{sideways}
\begin{talltblr}[
caption={abc},
  label={tab:sequence}
                ]{%
        colspec = {@{} Q[l,font=\bfseries] *{9}{c} @{}},
        row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
        row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=0.8ex},
                }
    \toprule
TIPOLOGIA   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
    \midrule
PESATURA    & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
PIANO       & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\

\# STRATI   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
SPESSORI (mm) 
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
GAP (mm)    & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
RIEMPIMENTO & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
COD AX      & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
COD SAG     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
COD COR     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
FOV (mm)    & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
RFOV (\%)   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
\# ECHI     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
GAP ECHI (ms) 
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
NSA& 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
TE (ms)     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
TI (ms)     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
MATRICE     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
AA          & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
DE          & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
REPHASE     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
ECHO SHIFT  & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{sideways}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

BTW: package `hyperref` should be (with rare exception) load last in preamble.

**Addendum:**
If you alow to use `\small` font size and that table can protrude to outer page border, than  by use of the `changepage` package can write table as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{extbook}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {4}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{SEQUENZE}

    \begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \small
caption{abc},
  label{tab:sequence}
    
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}
\begin{tblr}{%
        colsep = 3.3pt,
        colspec = {@{} Q[l,font=\bfseries] *{9}{X[c]} @{}},
        row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
        row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=0.8ex},
                }
    \toprule
TIPOLOGIA   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
    \midrule
PESATURA    & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
PIANO       & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\

\# STRATI   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
SPESSORI (mm) 
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
GAP (mm)    & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
RIEMPIMENTO & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
COD AX      & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
COD SAG     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
COD COR     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
FOV (mm)    & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
RFOV (\%)   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
\# ECHI     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
GAP ECHI (ms) 
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
NSA& 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
TE (ms)     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
TI (ms)     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
MATRICE     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
AA          & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
DE          & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
REPHASE     & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
ECHO SHIFT  & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880
            & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880   & 880x880 & 880x880 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{table}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]